# Using Context Bound with Higher Kinded Type?

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> trait Functor[F[_]] { 
  def fmap[A, B](f: A => B, func: F[A]): F[B]
}
```

and then the `something` function:

```
scala> def something[A, B, F[_]](f: A => B, x: A)
                                (implicit ev: Functor[F]): F[B] = 
     |   ev.fmap(f, ???)
something: [A, B, F[_]](f: A => B, x: A)(implicit ev: Functor[F])F[B]
```

How could I re-write `something` using Context Bounds for the `Functor` rather than the `implicit ev ...` mechanism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def something[A, B, F[_]](f: A => B, x: A)
                          (implicit ev: Functor[F]): F[B] = 
    ev.fmap(f, ???)
```

can be rewritten as:

```
def something[A, B, F[_]: Functor](f: A => B, x: A): F[B] = 
    implicitly[Functor[F]].fmap(f, ???)
```

This is using the implicitly method from Predef which just asks for an implicit parameter and returns it:

```
def implicitly[A](implicit a: A): A = a
```

As an aside, As the other answer points out, you seem to be missing an `F[A]`, which is perhaps why the second parameter to `fmap` is `???`, you perhaps want `x` to be typed `F[A]`, perhaps you want to change `Functor` to `Applicative` so that you can call `ev.fmap(f, ev.point(x))`

Comment: Thanks, Stew. Also, I've seen code within `cats` (can't recall where) that looked like: `def something[F : HigherKindedType[F]]...`. In other words, the higher-kinded type took itself as a type parameter. Could you please explain what that code is doing (and maybe a link to cats code)? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that is even legal scala, Don't know what you are referring to.